# Why is `typename` still necessary even the template type is declared as `class`?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, typename, type-deduction

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<class T> struct IsCharType          { enum { value = false }; };    
template<>        struct IsCharType<char>    { enum { value = true }; };    
template<>        struct IsCharType<wchar_t> { enum { value = true }; };

template<class CharType, class = enable_if<IsCharType<CharType>::value>::type>
struct MyString
{
    MyString()
    {}

    MyString(CharType*)
    {}
};

template<class CharType>
MyString<CharType> GetMyString(CharType* str) // error C2923
{
    return MyString<CharType>(str);
}

int main()
{}
```

My compiler is VC++ 2013 RC. The code above cannot be compiled because of the error C2923.

> error C2923: 'MyString' :
>   'std::enable_if::value,void>::type' is not a valid
>   template type argument for parameter ''

However, if I change

```
template<class CharType, class = enable_if<IsCharType<CharType>::value>::type>
```

to

```
template<class CharType, class = typename enable_if<IsCharType<CharType>::value>::type>
```

then it will be OK.

I just wonder why `typename` is necessary here? In this case, I have two reasons:

1. The compiler can deduce if the second template parameter is a type name; Because I decalred it as `class`.
2. Even if the compiler cannot deduce if it is a type name, as per the `SFINAE` rule, the compiler should not fail because the template function `GetMyString` is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not declared it as class. Your template parameter declaration

```
class = enable_if<IsCharType<CharType>::value>::type
```

is a declaration of an unnamed type parameter. We can give this parameter an explicit name,  e.g.

```
class U = enable_if<IsCharType<CharType>::value>::type
```

So in this case it is `U` that is declared as type parameter ("as class").

Meanwhile, everything to the right of `=` is not "declared as class". It is interpreted by the compiler in accordance with general rules, without any regard to the fact that it happens to be a default argument for a type parameter.

Logic like "since this is a default argument for a *type* parameter, the compiler must realize by itself that this is a type" does not apply here simply because the language specification does not say it applies. Moreover, the language standard actually says

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.

This means that the compiler is *required to assume* that

```
enable_if<IsCharType<CharType>::value>::type
```

is *not* a type, which is contrary to what you expect it to do.

The language does have a number of contexts where dependent name is unconditionally assumed to name a type. That includes constructor initializer lists, base class specifiers and elaborated type specifiers. But default arguments for template type parameter is not one of such contexts.

SFINAE does not save the situation here. SFINAE, as the name suggests, works at the time of substitution. Your code never gets to substitution, it breaks much earlier. It is simply an invalid template definition.

Comment: I mean `class = Something` explicitly indicates `SomeThing` is a type name. The compiler should know this.

Comment: @xmllmx: As I said above, there's no such thing as "should know" in C++ language. There's language spec that says what is well-formed code and what is ill-formed code. And if some code is ill-formed, the compiler must report it (and, usually, fail to compile it), even if to you it might look like the compiler "should know" what to do. The language spec does not say that in this case the compiler should figure it out. Instead, it says that `typename` is required in this case.

Comment: If the C++ standard requires to add 'typename` here, and it is indeed  not necessary, then, I think, the standard should relax this unnecessary restriction.

Comment: @xmllmx: You might be right. But the thing is that relaxing this restriction might make the specification more complicated. I.e. it will have to separate this situation into a separate case requiring special treatment. The other alternative is to keep the spec simpler  at the expense of requiring you to specify that `typename`. Apparently, they decided to stick with the latter approach for now.

Comment: I think your explanation may be the real rationale.

Comment: @xmllmx: In some contexts it is assumed to name a type without the requirement to specify `typename`. For example, when you specify base classes in class definition, `typename` is not needed (and not allowed). So, the language does follow your logic in some contexts. It is just that default arguments for templates is not one of such contexts for some reason.